# Python - duplicate columns to find data df pandas

Tags: pandas, duplicates, python-3.6

if I have a DataFrame:

```
 col1  |  col2  |  col3
  1    |   f    |    Y 
  1    |   t    |    G 
  2    |   b    |    Z 
  7    |   t    |    Y 
  2    |   f    |    Z 
  1    |   b    |    Y 
  7    |   b    |    Q 
  2    |   b    |    Q
  7    |   t    |    Q 
  2    |   c    |    Z
```

df = df[df.duplicated(['col1', 'col3'], keep=False)]

then get 'col2' different value to new dataframe.

`Like`

`1    |   f    |    Y` 
 `1    |   b    |    Y`

`Exclude`

`2    |   b    |    P` 
 `2    |   b    |    P`

```
 col1  |  col2  |  col3 
  1    |   f    |    Y 
  1    |   b    |    Y 
  2    |   b    |    Z 
  2    |   f    |    Z 
  2    |   c    |    Z 
  7    |   b    |    Q
  7    |   t    |    Q
```

How do I do this in python? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Used `df[df.duplicated(subset=['col1', 'col3'], keep=False)]`?

Comment: but i want to get  'col2' different , 
only use df.duplicated 'col2' have a lot same value

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

To get your output, just

```
ndf=df.loc[df[['col1', 'col3']].duplicated(keep=False)].sort_values(by='col1')

    col1    col2    col3
0   1       f       Y
5   1       b       Y
2   2       b       Z
4   2       f       Z
9   2       c       Z
6   7       b       Q
8   7       t       Q
```

Now, to get all different values of `col2`, use

```
ndf.col2.unique()

array(['f', 'b', 'c', 't'], dtype=object)
```

or you can drop the duplicates (but im not sure thats what you want)

```
ndf.drop_duplicates('col2')

    col1    col2    col3
0   1   f   Y
5   1   b   Y
9   2   c   Z
8   7   t   Q
```